# File open dialog doesn't actually point to the Home folder..?

Tags: kubuntu, chromium

Operating System: Kubuntu 22.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.24.7
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.92.0
Qt Version: 5.15.3
Kernel Version: 5.15.0-69-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 4 × Intel® Xeon® CPU E31225 @ 3.10GHz
Memory: 15.5 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: NV167

"Open Files" dialog in Chromium

If I click on the "Home" shortcut, I get an empty folder(?) and a number. If I want the actual "Home" location, I have to click on Documents, then on my user name, sort of working backwards to it. What's going on here, and is there a way to fix it? [image]

Comment: This is an application installed as a snap, and must be an issue with how it is packaged and configured.

Comment: ... perhaps something related to the `SNAP_REAL_HOME` environment variable setting? See for example [SNAP_REAL_HOME is kinda buggy](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/snap-real-home-is-kinda-buggy/34463/12)

Comment: @vanadium I believe you're right. steeldriver There isn't a SNAP_REAL_HOME environment variable in my list (kubuntu 22). If there's another config somewhere I'm not finding it.